# How to make strong type work with `uniform_int_distribution`

Tags: c++, boost, c++20, type-traits

I have introduced strong types in my project, as recommened by the [Cpp Core Guideline I.4](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#i4-make-interfaces-precisely-and-strongly-typed). I want to continue using `boost::random::uniform_int_distribution`, but I am faced with many issues:

[Example code:](https://godbolt.org/z/x1YKjMxMK)

```cpp
#include <boost/random/mersenne_twister.hpp>
#include <boost/random/uniform_int_distribution.hpp>

#include <cstdint>


struct grid_t {
    using value_type = int16_t;
    value_type value;

    auto operator==(const grid_t &other) const -> bool = default;
    auto operator<=>(const grid_t &other) const = default;
};


auto main() -> int {
    auto rng = boost::random::mt19937 {0};
    auto dist = boost::random::uniform_int_distribution<grid_t> {grid_t {5}, grid_t{10}};
    return dist(rng).value;
}
```

This doesn't compile and gives the error:

```
/opt/compiler-explorer/libs/boost_1_81_0/boost/random/traits.hpp:70:7: error: 
static assertion failed due to requirement 
'std::numeric_limits<grid_t>::is_specialized': std::numeric_limits<T>::is_specialized
      BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(std::numeric_limits<T>::is_specialized);
```

I thought of specializing `numeric_limits` like this:

```cpp
template <>
class std::numeric_limits<grid_t>
    : public std::numeric_limits<grid_t::value_type> {};
```

But this lead to an error `grid_t` not being integral, which I am not allowed to define, at least in `std`.

Is this possible, or should I abandon this idea and adapt `uniform_int_distribution` instead?

Comment: Why do you use boost and not the standard `<random>` header + std::mt19937  + std::uniform_int_distribution? https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/random

Comment: I need my random numbers to be reproducible across different compilers. Anyways, I tried `std::uniform_int_distribution` and get very similar errors ...

Comment: You still could use the distribution to generate a `int16_t` and *then* create a `grid_t` with that value. Pack the logic in a `uniform_grid_distribution` function, if you want.

Comment: It is honorable to introduce new type, but in this case instead trying fulfilling  `uniform_int_distribution` requirements for `grid_t` is complex task (even I'm not sure if it is not implementation specific). It is cheaper to use get `int16_t` random value and then convert it to  `grid_t`.

Comment: [Docks says:](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution) > IntType - The result type generated by the generator. The **effect is undefined if this is not one of** short, int, long, long long, unsigned short, unsigned int, unsigned long, or unsigned long long.

Comment: @MarekR Thank you, if you post your comment as an answer, I will accept it. The types are very similar in boost, so I guess it applies as well.